# Reading file from command window in C

Tags: c, file, visual-c++

at the moment i read in a file as demonstrated below in the code. However i would like to be able to type in the file's name and process that file in the same way, i am using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 express. The code:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

static const int MAX_FILE_ROWS = 10;

double lines[MAX_FILE_ROWS][4];
FILE *file = fopen("filename.txt", "r");

for (int i = 0; i < MAX_FILE_ROWS; i++){
if (feof(file))
    break;

fscanf(file, "%lf %lf %lf %lf", &(lines[i][0]), &(lines[i][1]), &(lines[i][2]), &(lines[i][3]));     
printf("%f %f %f %f\n", lines[i][0], lines[i][1], lines[i][2], lines[i][3]);
}

fclose(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

The signature of the main is:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]);
```

the argv[1] that is the second parameter would be the name of the file that you would enter. The first is the full path of the application itself, so

```
argv[1]
```

Would give you the first parameter of the command line argument. Replace the name of the file in your code with argv[1]. That is it.

So the code should look like this:

```
FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
```

Comment: for some reason MVC++ is saying fatal error despite the easy change

Comment: Ok. Just change the line to FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r"); and then when you call the prog from the command line just call it using prog.exe filename.txt. Assuming that the file is in the same folder as the prog.exe. Hope that helps.

Comment: @user1377485: Can you paste whatever relevant files on gist.github.com at least?